# angular 6 unit testing - how can I inject a class with static property for testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a class AppGlobal which get injected in the AppModule and then I am using this singleton class for creating dependencies instances.
but I am getting the following error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at new StopWatchComponent (webpack:///./src/app/UserSection/Components/StopWatchComponent.ts?:27:109)

```
 @Injectable()
export class AppGlobal {
AppModule.injector.get(MyService)`
  public static injector: Injector;
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    AppGlobal.injector = injector;
  }
 }
```

**component to be tested**

```
export class StopWatchComponent  implements OnInit {
      public title: string;
         private stopWatchService: StopWatchService;
      constructor() {
         this.stopWatchService = AppGlobal.injector.get(StopWatchService);
         console.log('constructor');
}
```

**root module**

```
export class AppModule {
      constructor(_appGlobal: AppGlobal) {
      }
}
```

**test cases**

```
describe('StopWatchComponent', () => {
  let component: StopWatchComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<StopWatchComponent>;
  // let el: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        FormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [ StopWatchComponent ],
      providers: [AppGlobal
        {provide: StopWatchService, useClass: StopWatchServiceMock}]
    }).compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('configureTestingModule ok');

      }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e.message);
      throw e;
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StopWatchComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

  }));

  it('should have title User stopwatch', () => {
    expect(component.title).toEqual('User stopwatch');
  });
```

Comment: Angular comes witha DI system, whose main objective is to make things testable. You transformed it back into a global static factory when components lookup their dependencies instead of using DI. And now you find out that it makes testing difficult. The est advice is: drop that AppGlobal, and use DI as it's supposed to be used.

Comment: @jb Nizet : I agree with you. this is just r&d i was doing to make the code generic. in actual code, I have a base component and all the logic of the injection goes there so that I don't have to inject any dependency from derived components i.e. activedroute, logservice, toster, utityservice etc. I will try some other design to make it testable. thanks for you comment